# How to use UpdatePanel trigger in ASPX page for User Control button

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls

I have a few textboxes and button in User Control.when I click on button, textboxes get updated and I am using Update panel.

I want to make panel visible in aspx page for the User control button. How can I do this ?

Comment: can you provide some of your code? ASPX Page?

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a public property or method in the User Control to handle setting the visibility.  You would be able to access that from the instance of the control on the aspx page.

Sample code for the property on the user control:

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public bool ButtonVisibility
    {
        set
        {
            SaveButton.Visible = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample code for accessing the property from the .aspx page:

```
public partial class Index : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            testControl.ButtonVisibility = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, can you please elaborate with some code. Thanks!